# Excel - Copy Range in ThisWorkbook and paste special in closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA

I am copying from an open workbook over to a closed workbook. It will paste values and formatting, but if I add paste special at the end of the range, I get "compile error - expected end statement". Help appreciated.

```
Sub vba_copy_Value_to_Inactive_Range()
Dim mybook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("E:\test file.xlsx")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Request").Range("E2").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("Request").Range("E4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

mybook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Copy` belongs on one line, and `PasteSpecial` on another.... see the linked dupe. Drop the `Destination:=` and move `wb.Sheets("Request").Range("E4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` to the next line.

Comment: I just did that and I still get an error.

Comment: What error message? Note that you don't need the clipboard. `wb.Sheets("Request").Range("E4").Value = 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Request").Range("E2").Value`.

Comment: Yes! That's all I was needing. Thank You!